# Is $(f+g)x=f(x)+g(x)$ always true?

Tags: functions

My Attempt: 
If Variable is same then  $$(f+g)x=f(x)+g(x)$$  it's always true.
Thanks in Advance..

Comment: Yes you're right

Comment: Yes, this is the definition of function addition. We define a new function $f + g$ by the above rule, i.e. the value of $f + g$ at $x$ is the sum of the values of $f$ and $g$ at $x$.

Comment: I would like to add that this definition may not be consistent, depending on the functions. Consider two functions $f,g : \mathbb{N} \to \{0,1\}$. $f(x)+g(x)$ may have no sense.

Comment: Yes, again depending on the context however, but I would adapt the notation accordingly. Writing $f+g$ strongly suggest something close to the relationship given by the OP. @sai-kartik

Comment: Makes sense @nicomenzi. Would rather stick to same variables to avoid confusion

Comment: I am asking in general... Is there is any contradict ex. for this..?

Comment: There isn't any contradiction to this. This is how function addition is **defined**. If you attempt to add two functions which don't have the same variable though, I'm not so sure this definition will still hold .

Answer (score 3):

The equation $(f+g)(x)=f(x)+g(x)$ is how addition of functions is generally *defined* (where “generally” here is more of a hedge word; I'm not aware of any other definition in use, however I don't want to completely exclude the possibility). It is called “pointwise addition”.

More exactly, if $A$ is an additive structure (that is, a set on which addition is defined), then given two functions $f:X\to A$ and $g:Y\to A$, then their sum is the function $(f+g):(X\cap Y)\to A$ with $(f+g)(x) = f(x)+g(x)$.

Answer (score 2):

Whenever it makes sense to talk about $f + g$, it's true. Specifically, it makes sense when:

- The domains of $f$ and $g$ to be the same set $A$,
- The codomains of $f$ and $g$ to be the same set $B$,
- The operation $+$ makes sense on $B$.

By the third point, I mean that $B$ is a set like $\Bbb{R}$, or $\Bbb{C}$, or $M_{2 \times 2}(\Bbb{R})$, or just some other set with some sensible addition defined on it. All we require is that the set be closed under the $+$ operation, i.e. $b_1 + b_2 \in B$ for all $b_1, b_2 \in B$.

For example, if $f, g : \Bbb{C} \to \Bbb{C}$ such that $f(z) = \overline{z}$ and $g(z) = |z|$, then $f + g$ makes sense, and we define $f + g : \Bbb{C} \to \Bbb{C}$ by
$$(f + g)(z) = f(z) + g(z) = \overline{z} + |z|.$$

If, on the other hand, we had $f : \Bbb{R} \to \Bbb{R}$ and $g : M_{2 \times 2}(\Bbb{R}) \to \Bbb{R}$ defined by $f(x) = 2x$ and $g(M) = \operatorname{Tr}(M) - 6$, then $f + g$ would not make sense, since $f$ and $g$ have different domains. We could not say $(f + g)(x) = f(x) + g(x)$, because it's not clear whether $x$ is a real number, or a two-by-two real matrix.

So yeah, whenever $f + g$ makes sense, what you wrote is true.